# Cypress test passes single form input field but ignores the following one(s)

Tags: cypress

I’m trying to test a Stripe form with 3 input fields in Cypress. I found an example that works to test  a single input that takes all the payment info (https://medium.com/@chipomapondera/hi-michael-98e432948028).

My version passes on inputting the CC but fails on the next input(s). My code is below:

```
it('checks user can support the Creator', () => {
        cy.get('button[class="buttons__FollowButton-sc-10ti9z2-0 huoUmA"]').click()
        cy.wait(4000)
        cy.get('body')
          .should('contain', 'Join this community')
        cy.get('button[class="styledComponents__SubscribeButton-g42pit-3 kUgWbq"]').click()
        cy.getWithinIframe('[name="cardnumber"]').type('4242424242424242')
          .getWithinIframe('[name="exp-date"]').type('1232')
          .getWithinIframe('[name="cvc"]').type('987')
    })
```

It doesn’t seem to like the following after it has typed the card number:
cy.getWithinIframe(‘[name=”exp-date”]’).type(‘1232’)
cy.getWithinIframe(‘[name=”cvc”]’).type(‘987’)

The error I receive is: 
[cypress error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1bHAi.png)

Answer (score 1):

That was the case I was struggled for several days.
I found out a solution.
I believe you integrated Stripe elements into your app, am I right.
If so, you should get the payment form elements inside the iframe using appropriate command chains.
Here is a third party [plugin](https://github.com/dbalatero/cypress-plugin-stripe-elements)

### Solution

#### Installation

```
npm install --save-dev cypress-plugin-stripe-elements
# or
yarn add --dev cypress-plugin-stripe-elements
```

Set `{ "chromeWebSecurity": false }` in your `cypress.json` file, or the plugin will not work.
Import the plugin in your cypress/support/index.js file:

```
// cypress/support/index.js

import 'cypress-plugin-stripe-elements';
```

#### TypeScript

Make sure to include the following types in your tsconfig.json file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "types": ["cypress", "cypress-plugin-stripe-elements"]
  }
}
```

#### Usage

```
describe('payment form', () => {
  it('allows for a successful payment', () => {
    cy.visit(`http://localhost:4000`);

    // It's recommended to scope `fillElementsInput` to a specific container
    // in case you have multiple Stripe Elements on the page.
    cy.get('#card-element').within(() => {
      cy.fillElementsInput('cardNumber', '4242424242424242');
      cy.fillElementsInput('cardExpiry', '1025'); // MMYY
      cy.fillElementsInput('cardCvc', '123');
      cy.fillElementsInput('postalCode', '90210');
    });

    // Click your Pay button (yours is different)
    // cy.get('#pay-button').click();

    // TODO: Assert some success state
  })
})
```

Click [here](https://github.com/dbalatero/cypress-plugin-stripe-elements) for check the reference link.

Please have a try and let me know if it works or not. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the medium article you shared and ran into the same issue as you. The cause of this problem is of course that stripe is creating multiple iframes and the method created in the article is just getting the first iframe.

So a very simple solution is to pass the id of the div containing the iframe to our getWithinIframe function. The function will now look like this:

```
Cypress.Commands.add('getWithinIframe', (iframeSelector, targetElement) =>
cy.get(`#${iframeSelector} iframe`).iframeLoaded().its('document').getInDocument(targetElement));
```

And call it like so:

```
cy.getWithinIframe('cardNumberElement','[name="cardnumber"]').type(1212123);
```

Hope this helps anybody who is facing the same issues.

Answer (score -1):

I could see a `typo` in the type field where there are `no ending` single quotes at this line of test `.getWithinIframe('[name="exp-date"]').type('1232)`. Could you please try following `.getWithinIframe('[name="exp-date"]').type('1232')`  or may be try without quotes `.getWithinIframe('[name="exp-date"]').type(1232)`

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I pasted it incorrectly. I have updated my question. The code still doesn't work :/